# Vector3.MoveTowards always puts me in the same place

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a block of code that grabs the position of a unit and the position where you clicked. I use .MoveTowards with the origin being the position of the unit and the target being the place where I clicked. However, when I do this, it always goes to the same location and I have no idea why.

Anyone have a similar experience and knows how to fix it?

Comment: You should show your code that demonstrates the issue. Please see [ask] for more guidelines

Comment: Did you tried this example http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html ? in your code ?

Comment: public static Vector3 MoveTowards(Vector3 current, Vector3 target, float maxDistanceDelta);
  Did you try increase the value of maxDistanceDelta?

Answer (score 0):

My way of doing this:

```
Vector3 mouseToWorld = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, mouseToWorld, 200f * Time.deltaTime);
```

Compare this to your code. Hope this was helpful.

Due the fact, of invoking this snippet in your Update method, you should consider to cache your transform in a variable, to avoid multiple GetComponent invokations unity is performing internally.